# Split php string and keep delimiter with the first output

Tags: php, split

I'm trying to split a php string in to parts the first one include the delimiter but the second one doesn't

```
$string = "abc==123";
```

What I want exactly is to get

```
$string['0'] = "abc==";
$string['1'] = "123";
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 5):

Simple enough

```
<?php
    $string = explode("==", $string);
    $string[0] .= "==";
?>
```

Comment: I already thought of doing that. i'm trying to do it in another way?!

Comment: @user2898514, while there are other ways, this is simple and works.

Comment: I guess, I'm just gonna go with it then

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want the function *strstr*

https://www.php.net/strstr

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's explode function,

```
$data  = "abc==123";
$result = explode("==", $data);
echo $result[0]. "==";
echo $result[1];
```

Comment: yah, but that will not include the "==" string with the first result thu

Comment: concatenate "==" in each result.